# Using EB Garamond Bold with pdfLaTeX

Tags: fonts, pdftex, overleaf, ebgaramond

So, [EB Garamond](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ebgaramond/) got an update in the end of last year.

Now it should also support **bold** text in pdfLaTeX, I supposed. But I still didn't get it working. Was I wrong to think that I could use my favourite font now in pdfLaTeX?

What I want is to use is Pardo's EB Garamond (the one that's also on Google Web Fonts).

I compile with pdfLaTeX on Overleaf btw.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%% nederlands
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

%% microtype
\usepackage{microtype}

%% lettertype garamond
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
```

Comment: I guess this font really doesn't have bold, does it?

Comment: Overleaf may not be using a font variation with your desires You would need to either build the fonts on your own system OR check with overleaf as to which styles they support for a given font since they are often behind due to compatibility for other users

Comment: (I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.) At present Overleaf indeed doesn't have this update of the ebgaramond package yet, sorry!

Comment: I see, do you think there would be some workaround for this in the mean time? (I tried some stuff with XeLatex but I also didn't get that to work).

Comment: Welkom op TeX.SE! A solution might be to install an up-to-date local distribution (e.g., TeX Live) and compile locally (possibly combined with version control software to allow easy collaboration).